# Spring Initializr Vanilla Project - Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError:

Tags: spring, spring-initializr

I created a bare-bones Spring Initializr project, but when I try to run it from the command line `java -jar demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` I get the following error:

```
java -jar demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/ConfigurationSource;)Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/Configuration;
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:490)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:460)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:256)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:561)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:578)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:214)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:145)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:41)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:182)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$Log4jLog.<clinit>(LogFactory.java:199)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$Log4jDelegate.createLog(LogFactory.java:166)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:109)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:99)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<clinit>(SpringApplication.java:200)
    at com.kgcontrols.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10)
    ... 8 more
```

How can I prevent this error?

Comment: Hi ! Welcome on stackoverflow, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more information on how to add a good question. You should be giving more context, more code, more explanations. The better your questions are, the more users will help you :)

Comment: Ok found the issue. The problem was that there were some slf4j.x.x.jar files under ~/Library/Java/Extensions, that were being loaded and conflicted